# Sewage treatment on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work

Is there a problem with flushing a toilet or sending other water into the US sewage treatment system on Shabbos if by doing so you are perhaps indirectly, causing the mechanical work involved in sewage treatment which includes melacha deoraisa such as kindling a fire?

[this question is related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10532/why-is-it-ok-to-use-tap-water-toilets-on-shabbos-considering-the-source-of-the)

Comment: How about the problem of hotzah

Comment: @sam I don't think such a problem exists for things traveling underground

Comment: @sam - Did you mean to say "tzo'ah" vs. "hotza'ah?"

Comment: @DanF, hope that was a joke cause i'm rolling! But n.a.t.c.m.n. is right about hotza'ah in this indirect situation. I think that Mr. 6641 should explain to us how the treatment works so we can figure out if its gramma vs psik reisha dilo nicha leih vs a nonjew doing something adaata dinafshei. Or maybe assur.

Comment: @sam - Yes, it was a joke ;-) Offhand, I think city sewage "runs on its own" (somewhat of a pun intentional, here, but you know what I mean). Similar to the mail, except that mail is cleaner :-) In other words, your flushing the toilet may not be "gramah" to a system that runs, anyway.

Comment: @sam http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47362/5323